# "Place" or "venue"?

Tags: meaning, differences, nouns

Do *place* and *venue* have the same meaning? If not, what are the differences and when do we use which?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A *venue* is a special kind of place:

> **venue** |ˈvenˌyoō|
>   *noun*
>   the place where something happens, esp. an organized event such as a concert, conference, or sports event : *the river could soon be the venue for a powerboat world championship event*. [NOAD]

Thus all venues are places, but not all places are venues. Your house, for example, is a place. The stadium in your city is a venue. Your house could be a venue, however, if you were to host some kind of gathering there.

Comment: Thanks. So a venue always relates to an event?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: A venue is a place to which people come for a purpose. The word derives from the French verb "venir" = to come. ++ From the Online Etymology Dictionary: **venue** (n.) c. 1300, "a coming for the purpose of attack," from Old French venue "coming" (12c.), from fem. past participle of venir "to come," from Latin venire "to come," from PIE root *gwa- "to go, come." The sense of "place where a case in law is tried" is first recorded 1530s. Extended to locality in general, especially "site of a concert or sporting event" (1857).